# Is it possible to install all available packages of TexLive in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, yum, latex

I would like to install all TexLive packages available for Fedora using Yum. All of them have the format `texlive-package`. Is there a way to do it all without installing one package at a time (there are more than 5000!)?

Answer (score 1):

If all the packages follow the pattern`textlive-<package>` you can use a regex to install them like so:

```
$ sudo yum install texlive-\*
```

You can also specify the pattern like this:

```
$ sudo yum install 'texlive-*'
```

**NOTE:** In either case we're protecting the pattern above from being interpreted as a glob by theshell.

#### Example

```
$ sudo yum install texlive-\*
...
...
 texlive-zxjafbfont              noarch      3:svn28539.0-0.1.fc19       updates    16 k
 texlive-zxjafbfont-doc          noarch      3:svn28539.0-0.1.fc19       updates    16 k
 texlive-zxjafont                noarch      3:svn30105.0.2-0.1.fc19     updates    18 k
 texlive-zxjafont-doc            noarch      3:svn30105.0.2-0.1.fc19     updates    131 k
 texlive-zxjatype                noarch      3:svn28541.0.6-0.1.fc19     updates    24 k
 texlive-zxjatype-doc            noarch      3:svn28541.0.6-0.1.fc19     updates    149 k
Installing for dependencies:
 python-pygments                 noarch      1.6-1.fc19                  updates    965 k
 t1utils                         x86_64      1.37-4.fc19                 fedora     70 k
 teckit                          x86_64      2.5.1-9.fc19                fedora     282 k
 zziplib                         x86_64      0.13.62-2.fc19              fedora     80 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================
Install  4867 Packages (+4 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 1.6 G
Installed size: 2.9 G
Is this ok [y/d/N]:·
```

#### Specifying package patterns

I highly encourage anyone that works with `yum` to thoroughly read the section titled: "SPECIFYING PACKAGE NAMES".

*excerpt*

> #### SPECIFYING PACKAGE NAMES
>
> A package can be referred to for install, update, remove, list, info
>   etc with any of the following as well as globs of any of the
>   following:
>
> ```
>          name
>          name.arch
>          name-ver
>          name-ver-rel
>          name-ver-rel.arch
>          name-epoch:ver-rel.arch
>          epoch:name-ver-rel.arch
>
>          For example: yum remove kernel-2.4.1-10.i686
>               this will remove this specific kernel-ver-rel.arch.
>
>          Or:          yum list available 'foo*'
>               will list all available packages that match 'foo*'. (The  
>               single quotes will keep your shell from expanding the 
>               globs.)
> ```

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could pass wildcards to "install".

Comment: Take a look at the man page for `yum`, it's all explained there.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum search texlive | grep '^texlive' | awk -p '{print $1}' > packages.txt
yum install $(cat packages.txt)
```

That will install every single TexLive package available.